# Self join in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
SELECT 
    FW1.id, count(*) 
FROM 
    firmware FW1 
LEFT JOIN
    firmware FW2 ON FW1.firmware_group_id = FW2.firmware_group_id
                 AND FW1.br_date < FW2.br_date 
                 AND FW2.[public]= '1'  
GROUP BY
    FW1.id
```

I am looking to convert into linq query. As I know less than symbol cannot be converted into Linq query. Please suggest how to do it. I have a string date and I need to compare into linq.

Comment: How about using [Linqer](https://www.sqltolinq.com/)?

Comment: Usually for such conditions, you'd just move it into a separate where clause.

Comment: @Keim, I tried Linqer, but the converted linqer code is giving an error while compiling in C#. Error is like  "CS1941  C# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'."

Comment: This is Linqer Code, but without date condition.                                       from FW1 in db.Firmware
join FW2 in db.Firmware
      on new { FW1.Firmware_group_id, Public = "1" }
  equals new { FW2.Firmware_group_id, FW2.Public } into FW2_join
from FW2 in FW2_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
group FW1 by new {
  FW1.Id
} into g
select new {
  g.Key.Id,
  Column1 = g.Count()
}    Note : It will give an error like "CS1941  C# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'."

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Linq does not support other types of `join` outside of EquiJoin. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations) is pretty clear on what you can do to bypass this:

- you could use a simple cross join (a cartesian product), then applying in the where clause the conditions for your non-equijoin.
- Or you could use a temporary variable to store a new table with only the attributes you need for your query and, like before, applying the conditions in the where clause.

In your case, a possible Linq query could be this one:

```
from f1 in firmwares
from f2 in firmwares
let f1_date = DateTime.Parse(f1.Dt)
let f2_date = DateTime.Parse(f2.Dt)
where f1.Group_Id == f2.Group_Id && f1_date < f2_date
group f1 by f1.Id into fres
select new {
    Id = fres.Key,
    Count = fres.Count()
};
```

However I am still thinking how to emulate the `LEFT JOIN` without casting it to a group join.

Comment: I tried this, but the issue is I am not able to convert string date to date time format for comparison. For example my date is like yyyyMMdd format - 20130530, I need to convert this String date format to datetime format. I have tried at my end like - DateTime.ParseExact(r.br_date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) which give an error like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: That's weird, are you sure the format of `r.br_date` is exactly that? Because I tried with the line you wrote and it is returns a `DateTime`.

Comment: Yes, r.br_date format is yyyyMMdd only and its a string in DB side.

Comment: Basically this is my SQL Query and I tried to rewrite in LINQ. All the column datatypes are string only.Here is the SQL Query which is running fine at SQL Environment :                                                                 SELECT 
 FW1.id, count(*) 
FROM 
 firmware FW1 
left join 
 firmware FW2
ON 
 FW1.firmware_group_id = FW2.firmware_group_id
and
 FW1.br_date < FW2.br_date 
and
 FW2.[public]= '1' 
 group by 
 FW1.id

Answer (score 0):

**Of course the `<` symbol can be used. Just use method syntax instead of query syntax!**

Every `FW1` has zero or more `FW2s`. Every `FW2` belongs to exactly one `FW1`. This one-to-many is implemented using foreign key `firmware_group_id`.

Apparently you want all `FW1s`, each with the number of its `FW2s`, that have a property `public` with a value equal to 1 and a property `br-date` larger than the value of the `br-date` of the `FW1`.

Whenever you want an item with its many sub-items (using a foreign key), like s School with its Students, a Customer with his Orders, a Book with his Pages, you'll need [Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var result = FW1.GroupJoin(FW2,      // GroupJoin FW1 and FW2
    fw1 => fw1.firmware_group_id,    // from fw1 take the primary key firmware_group_id
    fw2 => fw2.firmware_group_id,    // from fw2 take the foreing key firmware_group_id

    (fw1, fw2s) => new               // from every fw1, with all its matching fw2s 
    {                                // make one new object containing the following properties:
        Id = fw1.Id,

        // Count the fw2s of this fw1 that have public == 1
        // and a date larger than fw1.date
        Count = fw2.Where(fw2 => fw2.Public == 1 && fw1.br_date < fw2.br_date)
                   .Count(),         
    });
```

Note:

Comment: @Coppoolse, I have tried this, but it will not working for me. I appreciate your thoughts. But more over I am looking for self join in Linq and compare the string date with less (<) Operator. I have already described the issues on my above post.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what would you do if you had a LEFT JOIN like in this issue, but only the condition `FW1.br_date < FW2.br_date` in the join condition? How do you translate this?